# What is the consequence of a set not obeying the least upper bound axiom?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

What is the consequence of a set not obeying the least upper bound axiom? How does it limit the set?

For example if a set does not obey LUB then it will not have to necessarily obey any theorems derived from it, right?

Comment: What?${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean here. The least upper bound axiom states that if a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ is bounded above, then it has a least upper bound. If the subset is not bounded above, then it does not have a least upper bound.

Comment: Do you want an example of a set where the least upper bound axiom is not valid?

Comment: Upper bounds are not defined in the context of a bare set. They are only defined in the context of a set equipped with an order relation, what we call an "ordered set". Perhaps what you *really* wanted to ask is something like this: "What is the consequence of an *ordered* set not obeying the least upper bound axiom?"

Answer (score 2):

I'm not really sure what you mean, but I can try to give an example. $\mathbb{Q}$ does not satisfy the least upper bound axiom, and one of its problems is "we can't always take limits". That is, if a sequence is increasing and bounded above, intuitively it *should* have a limit (the supremum), but in $\mathbb{Q}$ this is not always the case. For example, the sequence $3, 3.1, 3.14, 3.141, 3.1415, 3.14159, ...$ has no limit in $\mathbb{Q}$.

Answer (score 1):

It means the space is *incomplete*. It means set that is bounded above may not have a least upper bound.  As a result you may have a sequence of terms that "hone in" but not actually have a limit to "strive for".

For example the rationals are incomplete.  The set of $K=\{q\in \mathbb Q| q^2 \le 2\}$ is bounded above (if $q \in K$ then $q< 1.42$ so it is bounded above).  But the set has no least upper bound. Likewise it has no maximum element.  If $q$ is rational and $q^2 \le 2$ then $q^2 < 2$ and there is a $q' > q$ so that $q^2 < q'^2 < 2$.  ANd if $r$ is rational and $r^2 \ge 2$ then $r^2 > 2$ and you can always find an $r' < r$ so that $2 < r'^2 < r$.

And we can have a sequence of $q_1= 1.4$ and $q_2 = 1.41$ and $q_3 = 1.414$ and so on so $q_k = \sqrt{2}$ rounded to $k$ digits.  Then it should *look* like $q_k$ should have a limit as they all "huddle" closer and closer to.  It looks like they all want to huddle around a positive $\omega$ where $\omega^2 = 2$ and that the limit would be $\omega$. But it doesn't have a limit.  There is no rational number $\omega$ so that $\omega^2 = 2$.

So $\lim_{n\to \infty} q_n$ does not exist in $\mathbb Q$.

(There's an *irrational* number $\sqrt 2$ so that $(\sqrt 2)^2 =2$ but that number doesn't exist in the rationals.)

=====

On second reading, it seems you may be asking about a set in $\mathbb R$.  $\mathbb R$ has the least upper bound property that all sets that are bounded above have a least upper bound.  It could be you are asking what can we say about a set that breaks that rule.  You could be asking what do we know about a set that is bounded above but doesn't have a least upper bound.

And what we can say is .... there is no such set.  The least upper bound is a rule.  *Every* set (in the reals) that is bounded above will have a (real) least upper bound.

Comment: Yes but isn't the set K which you described above a set in the reals, since all rational numbers are also real numbers?

Comment: Yes, but isn't the set K which you described above a set in the reals? Also I meant that if we consider the Nested Interval theorem (which I believe may be derived from LUB), it means that the set K (which doesn't obey LUB) does not have to necessarily obey the Nested Interval theorem either, or any other theorem derived from LUB, right?

Comment: "Yes but isn't the set K which you described above a set in the reals, since all rational numbers are also real numbers?"  So?  A set can be a subset of just about any larger set you want.  The set $K$ (which is $(-\sqrt{2},\sqrt{2})\cap\mathbb Q$) is also a subset of {numbers and elephants}.  That set {numbers and elephants} has the "sometimes eats hay property".  But $K$ does not because the "sometimes eats hay property" like the "least upper bound" property isn't inherited by the subsets.

Comment: We don't usually apply the LUB principal to the actual *sets* but to a "space".   The set $L= [0,1)\cup (3,4]$ doe not have the least upper bound principal because $(0.5,1)\subset L$ and $(0.5,1)$ is bounded above by $3.5$.  But there is no least upper bound in $L$.  That $L$ *itself* doesn't have a LUB property but, say $(0,1)$ does is not very interesting.  BUt that $\mathbb R$ does is.  It means that $(0.5,1)$ *does* have a lub in $\mathbb R$.

Comment: I'm not trying to show that $K$ doesn't have the lub property.  $K$ could be any other subset.  I'm trying to show that $\mathbb Q$, itself, doesn't have the lub property.  And as a result $K$ does not have a rational lub.  And no, $\mathbb Q$ does obey the nested inerval theorem.  (Let. $\{a_i\}$ and $\{b_i\}$ be a series of rational numbers where $2-\frac 1{i-1} < a_i^2 < 2-\frac 1i$ and $2+\frac 1i < b_i^2 < 2+\frac 1{1-i}$ then $[a_{k+1},b_{k+1}]\subset [a_k, b_k]$ but $\cap_{n\in \mathbb N}[a_n,b_n] = \emptyset$.